# Entity Framework IValidatableObject reference DbContext

Tags: c#, validation, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I'm trying to get EF 4.1 working with Repository, UnitOfWork, separation of entities from EF and validation.

I followed [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) guide to get a nice separation of my POCO entities from the EF model and I'm now following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/27/ef-4-1-validation.aspx) guide to implement validation (with IValidatableObject).

My solution consists of:

- Contacts.Repository [references EF and Contacts.Entities]:

  - Contacts.edmx
  - ContactsDbContext.cs
- Contacts.Entities [no references]:

  - Contact.cs (Contacts.Entities.Contact partial class)
- Contacts.Validation [references Contacts.Entities and Contacts.Repository]

  - Contact.cs (Contacts.Entities.Contact partial class)

But I'm hitting a brick wall with the validation:

1. I cannot add validation logic to Contacts.Entities because it would cause a circular reference with Contacts.Repository (contact.Validate(...) needs to use ContactsDbContext).  So I created a separate Contacts.Validation project.
2. But, this means splitting the Contact class with partial classes to define Contact inside both Contacts.Entities and Contacts.Validation.  The code no longer compiles because you can't define a partial class accross different assemblies.

Anyone got any pointers for me here?  I've posted the code below...

Contacts.Repository.ContactsDbContext.cs:

```
namespace Contacts.Repository
{
  public partial class ContactsDbContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
      items.Add("Context", this);
      return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
  }
}
```

Contacts.Entities.Contact.cs:

```
namespace Contacts.Entities
{
    public partial class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Contacts.Validation.Contact.cs contains:

```
namespace Contacts.Entities
{
  public partial class Contact : IValidatableObject
  {
      public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
      {
          ContactsDbContext contacts = (ContactsDbContext)validationContext.Items["Context"];

          //Check if Contact already exists with the same Name
          if (contacts.Any<Contact>(c => c.Name == this.Name))
            yield return new ValidationResult("Contact 'Name' is already in use.", new string[] { "Name" });

          yield break;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Technically* you could introduce an interface with an explicit implementation like so:

In **Contacts.Entities** assembly:

```
public interface IContactsDbContext
{
    IQueryable<Contact> Contacts { get; }
    // Not DbSet<Contact> because you don't want dependency on EF assembly 
}

//...

public class Contact : IValidatableObject // No partial class anymore
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        IContactsDbContext context = 
            validationContext.Items["Context"] as IContactsDbContext;

        if (context.Contacts.Any<Contact>(c => c.Name == this.Name))
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "Contact 'Name' is already in use.", new string[] { "Name" });

        yield break;
    }
    // IValidatableObject, ValidationResult and ValidationContext is in
    // System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll, so no dependency on EF
}
```

In **Contacts.Repository** assembly (references *Contacts.Entities* assembly):

```
public class ContactsDbContext : DbContext, IContactsDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    IQueryable<Contact> IContactsDbContext.Contacts // explicit impl.
    {
        get { return Contacts; } // works because DbSet is an IQueryable
    }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(
        DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        items.Add("Context", this);
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
}
```

**Contacts.Validation** assembly can be removed.

However, I do not really like this solution. Your POCO has - through the `Validate` method - still a dependency on the repository, if interface or not. For a stronger separation of concerns I would probably prefer to have a separate Validation class which does perhaps also operations on the repo. Or if I would implement `IValidatableObject` I would probably only do validations which depend on model object properties alone (things like "production date must not be later than shipping date" and so on). Well, it's partially a matter of taste. The second example you have linked does not really care about separation of concerns, so you have somehow a conflict with the first example.

Comment: Thanks. - thats a step closer.  I agree, I'd prefer more separation of concerns.  How would you normally separate out Validation from the Repository (regardless of EF)?  I have a good Validation and Repository pattern that gives complete separation... but then you have the issue that the caller may not call the Validate before calling the Save on the Repository.

NB - now I'm faced with referencing Entity Framework in the callers because the validation will raise a System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException type.  I'm finding this to be an annoying fight against EF!!!

Comment: @Matt: I don't have a clean separation between validation and repo. The validation that a particular field must be unique is from my viewpoint not a validation on entity level. It could also be considered as a validation of the repo (the repo would become invalid *if* I'd insert an entity with same name). Usually I access my repos through service classes and there I do a "check" before I insert if there is already an entity with same name. Not a cleanly separated validation. It might become easier and cleaner when EF provides the "Unique Constraints" feature mentioned in the second blog post.

Comment: I'm using DataAnnotation to provide entity level validation.  I agree the uniqueness check is a different level of validation and it shouldn't really be on the entity.  TBH, I feel like EF is forcing me down this path.  I'll look at moving it into the repository.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Slauma I'd suggest promoting your comment to an answer in its own right ;-)

Comment: @Slauma I'm late to the party here but I'm having trouble with this solution.  MVC is validating before the EF validation.  They both hit the same Validate method in the entity, but the model validation doesn't use the ValidateEntity override, so the context isn't there.  I don't want to turn off the model validation though, because of the UI convenience.  Anything I can do?  Thanks.  Edit: I have code [in my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773522/mvc-and-ef-validation-with-added-validationcontext-item)

Answer (score 1):

The validation that a particular field must be unique is from my viewpoint not a validation on **entity** level. It could also be considered as a **validation of the repo** (the repo would become invalid if I'd insert an entity with same name).

Usually I access my repos through service classes and there I do a "check" before I insert if there is already an entity with same name. Not a cleanly separated validation. It might become easier and cleaner when EF provides the "Unique Constraints" feature mentioned in the second blog post.

~ [Slauma Jun 28 '11 at 17:14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495157/entity-framework-ivalidatableobject-reference-dbcontext#comment7660422_6497228)

*this comment deserved to be an answer*