# Custom ValidationContext for EF?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I'm using EF as my dataprovider to save and validate my items.
I have some custom validation logic which needs access to other services or items.
I know the ValidationContext class supplies these options.
My question is how can I get my own validation context with an service provider or item to EF?

When I implement the IValidateObject interface on my POCO entity I get an instance of the validation context, but where can I make sure my own ValidationContext is used instead of the EF default one?

I want to base some validation on the fact that a service or item is available in the ValidationContext

Comment: Yes, I have a service layer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the ValidationContext you need to override DbContext.ValidateEntity(). The method takes two parameters - entity entry and items. You would pass your validation context in the items dictionary. Take a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495157/entity-framework-ivalidatableobject-reference-dbcontext).

Comment: Thanks! I can use the ValidateEntity override indeed!

Comment: Your article is gone. Please post the relevant parts and context in your answer.

Comment: Replaced the link to the post with a link to a stackoverflow question.