# Where to validate individual properties when editing an existing entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm using `Entity Framework 6` and the repository pattern, with a service layer on top. In my POCO entity classes, I do use `DataAnnotations` for basic requirements such as `KeyAttribute` and `RequiredAttribute`. I perform business-specific validation in my service layer, though. So for example, my `AccountService` has an `Insert` method for inserting a new `Account`. I'll do checks like whether or not an account is eligible to be created based on some business rules, etc. If it's not eligible then I'll throw a validation exception there.

A problem that I'm trying to solve is what about when an existing `Account` is being updated? Where would I perform validation for changes to individual properties of `Account`? In my repository pattern implementation, I have a unit of work object which contains the `DbContext` and the unit of work class only exposes my individual services (which use that `DbContext`) as well as a single `SaveChanges` method, which just calls the `DbContext`'s `SaveChanges` method. So, to update an existing `Account`, you would fetch it using the service layer, it'd be tracked by the `DbContext` and you'd edit the needed properties and call `SaveChanges`. There is no `Edit` method on my service that forces the user of my library to pass through that for validation.

Where should I perform this kind of validation?

Edit: I'd also be open to a way to make it so that some kind of `Edit` method is required, and that fetching existing entities does not track whem in the `DbContext`. I think this might complicate things such as lazy loading and stuff, though.

Comment: When you have to go to the database then you need to use DbContext and DbContext has an Overridable method called ValidateEntity http://stackoverflow.com/a/19406993/150342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using DataAnnotations, look at implementing [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This will allow you to encapsulate the extended validation inside the class. There is an example of using it in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject)

Comment: Doesn't this move even more business logic into the POCO? I already feel like DataAnnotations are too much, which is why I try to do as much as possible inside my service layer. For example, now my entity classes will need to access my repositories for certain validation logic. If I were hacking together a quick prototype, I would definitely go this `IValidatableObject` route, but in my current case I'm trying to separate concerns as much as I can.

Comment: Well either the entity should know how to validate its own data or you need to create a separate validator class which your service uses to validate an object prior to passing it to your repository

Comment: Yea, that second scenario is exactly what I'm trying to solve, except for an existing entity from a repository. An entity has been fetched and modified, there is no method required to add it back to the repository other than calling `DbContext`'s `SaveChanges` method. I guess I could override that and perform validation in there.

Comment: That's why I suggested IValidatableObject as it's part of DataAnnotations anyway so it should get invoked by the DbContext when it validates the object.

Comment: I guess using `IValidatableObject` works pretty well for simple validation. Overriding `Validate` on my `DbContext` can be used for more complex validation, needing to hit the database. Although I dislike how my validation is now split up into 2 different areas, and neither ended being my service layer. :(