# ASP .NET Model Validation: Is it ok to access DBContext inside the Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

Working with ASP .NET MVC I have a model called `Entity1` and I need to do a custom validation inside of it.

I searched for a while and found out that implementing `IValidatableObject` I could implement the `Validate` method to do what I want. Now the question I have in this process is that I need to validate a property of `Entity1` with another property of related `Entity2` (by related I mean *Data base relationship*).

What I have is this:

```
public partial class Entity1: IValidatableObject
{
    private EntitiesContext db = new EntitiesContext ();

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!Validation1())
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(@"Error message.", new[] { "Property1" });
        }
    }

    private bool Validation1()
    {
        if (this.Property1 != db.Entity2.First().Property2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, but **what I'm trying to figure out is if the use of "db" object to make the validation is well done right there.** Obviously I can polish it later with some Dependency Injection, but I want to be sure if this is the right way to make that kind of validation or if another way exists to achieve exactly that.

PS: I tried to access the relationship like this too, but the relationship is always `null`:

```
this.Property1 != this.Entity2.Property2
```

In the later, `this.Entity2` is always null.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Briefly discussed this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31527559/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold don't know what's wrong on my side but `validationContext.Items.Count` is zero when it reaches the `Validate` method.

Comment: Forgot an essential part, see the edited answer over there.

Comment: @GertArnold Ok so I overwrote that method in my DbContext, still doesn't work. I set a breakpoint inside of it and it never gets hit so so the `Items` property of `validationContext` is still zero. Reviewed everything and didn't get to what's wrong... any ideas?